# Phonegap 6.4.2 iframe on iOS10 not loading

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe

I recently found a bug on my phonegap application.
So, I decided to correct it (nice!) and I needed to update phonegap client to the new version 6.4.2.
Once done, I ran my application via "*phonegap serve*" and test my app on Android device and an iPhone device (with iOS 10).
Our application is a simple HTML page with an iframe inside in order to encapsulate our responsive design website.

Everything works great on Android **AND** on old iPhone (iOS 7.1.2) but on the new iPhone with iOS 10, the iframe doesn't load !!!
I search for a long time why... I do not understand...

So, I planned to create a new application

*phonegap create TestApp*

Here is the index.html code

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src gap://ready file://* *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; frame-src *; ">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe id="webview" src="https://www.google.com" onload="checkPage();"> 
    </iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize(); 
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It's really the started page with an iframe inside and this iframe doesn't load and the checkPage() is never fired.
I tried to change "Content-Security-Policy" but... did not work...

I'm out of ideas, so, if somebody had the same issue and know how to resolve this... You're welcome !

Thanks,
I can provide you more code if you want

Laurent

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found in this question:
[Cordova iOS blank iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572537/cordova-ios-blank-iframe)

Simply add the following to your config.xml file:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Comment: Yes, i read about that but it doesn't work...
Did you try to create quickly an example app ?

Comment: I eventually ended up doing this:
        `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">`